# Ruby rails - elegant way to render one form out of lot of forms in a view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have around 20 different possible forms, I want only one form to be displayed according to the user's selection. My solution to that is pretty low grade, using javascript to hide every other than the selected one. Plus I have to modify few form values dynamically using javascript based on user's selection. 
It is not a neat way to render/manage them, plus I want it to be flexible for future modifications. It's very messy right now, looking at it makes me sick. Anybody have better ideas on this?

This is how I have been doing -

```
<a class="font12" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('form2').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('form3').style.display='none'; return false;">form1</a>
```